# Intercept a toast notification windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, toast

I am trying to intercept a toast notification from a facebook app to make my own customized app but I cant seem to find any information on how to intercept a toast notification from a 3rd party app from my own app.

Is it possible to intercept a toast notification from some other app in my app on windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. It looks like a scam for me. Use your own notifications from [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/).