# event listener trigger when notification box pop-up in windows phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, event-handling, windows-phone

I could not find an understandable, reliable and useful links or sites that appropriate to the specific things that i'm looking for...

--
is there anybody here who can give me a link or tutorial that discusses about event listener in which will be trigger when the notification box pop-up (I mean the notification box of a reminder) ...and it will read the content of the reminder...Thank you so much for help

sample application with codes would be a great help so I can understand it more clearly, because I am beginner, thanks....

[an apology if this post might be misunderstood by the others]

by the way i'm using visual studio 2012 ultimate, and currently creating a windows phone app using C#...

I have visited this sites;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your app to perform some action when a reminder (created by any application). is triggered in Windows Phone. There is no way to do this.

Comment: but I thought event listener could do that, I have created a simple reminder application but aside from pop-up notification and single beep..I want that this reminder can speak too. it just have to read the content of the reminder...



-like talking alarm clock, but this will be a talking reminder. (using speech-to-text service)..ty

Answer (score 0):

This [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071136/intercept-a-toast-notification-windows-phone) suggests it's not possible, but without any explanation.

Comment: the explanation is simple, you cannot to it, there is nothing in the SDK that would allow you to